# Complex function analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

In the book i'm reading we have the following situation: Given a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with $|f(t)| \leq K$ constant for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Fix a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and consider de function 
$$g(z) = \sqrt\frac{n}{\pi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(t)e^{-n(t - z)^2}dt.$$

The author says that the Lebesgue convergence theorem imply that this function is analytic. I don't see why.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{g(z + h) - g(z)}{h} = \sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) \,\frac{e^{-n(t-z-h)^2} - e^{-n(t-z)^2}}{h} \,dt
$$
If you can convince yourself that 
$$
\left|f(t) \,\frac{e^{-n(t-z-h)^2} - e^{-n(t-z)^2}}{h}\right| \leq k(t) 
$$
for some $k(t) \in L^1$ (which you should be able to using the boundedness of $f$ and standard manipulations of the exponential terms), then you can use the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to commute the integral and the limit as $h \to 0$:

$$
\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{g(z + h) - g(z)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) \,\frac{e^{-n(t-z-h)^2} - e^{-n(t-z)^2}}{h} \,dt \\
\stackrel{DCT}{=}\sqrt{\frac{n}{\pi}} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t) \,\lim\limits_{h \to 0}\frac{e^{-n(t-z-h)^2} - e^{-n(t-z)^2}}{h} \,dt
$$
and hence can pass arguments of differentiability of $g$ to the differentiability of the exponential term.